# Is fixed width website of 768px, the best option for supporting all tablets an desktops?

Tags: website-design, resolution

I'm building a website, not interested in fluid design as I want to keep the line breaks of the paragraphs in the same certain way, for all resolution.

If the Ipad width is 768px on portrait, does it mean that If I want to create a website that would look good on all tablets and desktops pc's, my best bet would be to use a fixed width of 768px and not larger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not all when you consider many of the Samsung Galaxy tablets have a width of only 600px. And then there's my desktop monitor which is 1920px making your width about 1/3 of its width (if I were to view the browser full size). http://screensiz.es/tablet

As you can see, this is a problem all developers face and why responsive is the only real solution.

Comment: is there a way to have both responsive design and have line breaks that would work the same? does responsive essentially mean defining widths by % rather than px, or there's more to it?

Comment: @jayjay This can be done without percent, assuming the browsers you are targeting can handle the media property. In that case, you can set a break point where the px width of an element changes when the width of the browser hits that mark.